# Why the droid is making a nonstop circles around a waypoint ? And how should I repair this behaviour?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In most of the times it's moving fine between the waypoints but sometimes the droid make circles around a waypoint nonstop. I need then to stop the game and run it over again.

I tried to stand in the middle of the droid path moving the player first person, maybe that cause the problem ?

I added some waypoints on the stairs to let the droid move up/down the stairs and then after some rounds moving between the waypoints he started making circles around one of the waypoints on the stairs.

The droid is floating in the air. The droid have a animator , box collider , rigidbody :

[image: Droid inspector settings]

This is the script for the waypoints :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Waypoints : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject objectToMove;
    public GameObject[] waypoints;
    public Transform target;
    public float moveSpeed = 1f;
    public float rotationSpeed = 1f;

    private Transform myTransform;
    private int targetsIndex = 0;
    private Vector3 originalPosition;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        if (objectToMove == null)
        {
            myTransform = transform;
        }
        else
        {
            myTransform = objectToMove.transform;
        }

        originalPosition = myTransform.position;

        if (waypoints.Length == 0)
        {
            waypoints = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Waypoint");
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        WayPointsAI();
        DrawLinesInScene();
    }

    private void WayPointsAI()
    {
        if (targetsIndex == waypoints.Length)
            targetsIndex = 0;
        target = waypoints[targetsIndex].transform;
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(myTransform.position, target.transform.position);
        myTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(myTransform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(target.position - myTransform.position), rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        //move towards the player
        myTransform.position += myTransform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        if (distance < 0.3f)
            targetsIndex++;
    }

    void DrawLinesInScene()
    {
        // draw lines between each checkpoint //
        for (int i = 0; i < waypoints.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            Debug.DrawLine(waypoints[i].transform.position, waypoints[i + 1].transform.position, Color.blue);
        }

        // draw a line between the original transform start position 
        // and the current transform position //
        Debug.DrawLine(originalPosition, myTransform.position, Color.red);

        // draw a line between current transform position and the next waypoint target
        // each time reached a waypoint.
        if (target != null)
            Debug.DrawLine(target.transform.position, myTransform.position, Color.green);
    }
}
```

I tested it again now and I found that if the player is not standing in the middle of the droid path it will not happen. but if I stand in the middle of the droid path it will pass me the player but then will start making circles on the next waypoint.

Comment: I tested it again now and I found that if the player is not standing in the middle of the droid path it will not happen. but if I stand in the middle of the droid path it will pass me the player but then will start making circles on the next waypoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The droid has to come within 0.3f of the target waypoint "if (distance < 0.3f)", if the driod doesn't come within that distance the targetIndex will not increment.

It looks as if the combination of moveSpeed and rotationSpeed are to big to allow the droid to get within 0.3f of the target therefore it just orbits.

Try increasing the 0.3f distance and you should be able get the result you want.

Increasing rotationSpeed and/or decreasing moveSpeed will also help.

Comment: Ok I changed this settings this is one problem. but I found now that if me the player is standing in the path in the middle path of the droid while he is moving when he collide with me the player he is not continue the movement since he moved and stuck in the wall it seems like I pushed him to the side.  and maybe since the player me also have a character controller and a rigidbody too when the droid collide with me it's making problems. Not like navmesh agent he does not know how continue.

Comment: Is there a way to make the droid avoid collisions and tell him to find and keep moving on the path ? I can't use navmesh agent since the droid is in the air not on the floor.

Comment: Your droid logic is pretty simple, just rotate towards target and move forward. Makes it quite easy for the droid to get stuck behind an object. Navmesh agents can still work even though you droid is in the air, but you might have to manually control vertical position in some situations such as going up stairs. You could turn collisions off but I don't think that is the effect you are looking for, the droid would then pass through the player, not go around it.